# Halide Tuple usage

Tags: c++, computer-vision, halide

I want to use Halide to generate multiple output buffer.

```
Func output;
std::vector<Expr> argsExpr( 4 );
argsExpr[ 0 ] = aOut( x, y );
argsExpr[ 1 ] = bOut( x, y );
argsExpr[ 2 ] = cOut( x, y );
argsExpr[ 3 ] = dOut( x, y );
output( x, y ) = Tuple( argsExpr );
```

This example works fine, but I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple Output, but not the same size, like:

```
std::vector<Expr> argsExpr( 4 );
argsExpr[ 0 ] = aOut( x, y, c );
argsExpr[ 1 ] = bOut( x, y );
argsExpr[ 2 ] = cOut( x, y );
argsExpr[ 3 ] = dOut( x, y );
output( x, y, ? ) = Tuple( argsExpr );
```

I got an error from Halide about the difference between output 0 and output 1.

I assume that I want only one compilation (compile_to_file), not multiple Object files.

Jay

Answer (score 3):

Currently all outputs (elements of a Realization) must have the same number of dimensions, mins, and extents. Only the type of the elements can vary. Andrew has a plan to remove this restriction, but I would not depend on it for anything less than six to nine months out.